# PHP, $this->{$var} -- what does that mean?

Tags: php

I have encountered the need to access/change a variable as such:

```php
$this->{$var}
```

The context is with CI datamapper get rules. I can't seem to find what this syntax actually does. What do the `{`'s do in this context?

Why can't you just use:

```php
$this->var
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is a **variable variable**, such that you will end up with `$this->{value-of-$val}`.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

So for example:

```
$this->a = "hello";
$this->b = "hi";
$this->val = "howdy";

$val = "a";
echo $this->{$val}; // outputs "hello"

$val = "b";
echo $this->{$val}; // outputs "hi"

echo $this->val; // outputs "howdy"

echo $this->{"val"}; // also outputs "howdy"
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/QNds9

This of course is working within a class context. You can use variable variables in a local context just as easily like this:

```
$a = "hello";
$b = "hi";

$val = "a";
echo $$val; // outputs "hello"

$val = "b";
echo $$val; // outputs "hi"
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/n16sk

Comment: hmm `$object->attr` = `$object->{"attr"}` :)

Comment: I remember when I started, I tried to do something like `$this->$val` and failed miserably. Nice to see this answer up.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning the point of multiple `$`. Given the following code `$foo=1; $bar="foo"`, `$$bar` is 1.

Comment: are the curlies really neccesary? i have cases where the curlies are omitted

Comment: @Fuseteam They are not always necessary for simple variable names, no. But you can get into trouble with more complex variable names, and I find it to be a good practice. 

From the PHP docs: "Curly braces may also be used, to clearly delimit the property name. They are most useful when accessing values within a property that contains an array, when the property name is made of multiple parts, or when the property name contains characters that are not otherwise valid (e.g. from json_decode() or SimpleXML)."

Comment: @jszobody Ah thanks didn't know of the other types of complex variables other than variables with indices

Comment: Curly brace access syntax is deprecated since PHP 7.4

Answer (score 12):

First of all `$this->{$var}` and `$this->var` are two very different things. The latter will request the `var` class variable while the other will request the name of the variable contained in the string of `$var`. If `$var` is the string `'foo'` then it will request `$this->foo` and so on.

This is useful for *dynamic programming* (when you know the name of the variable only at runtime). But the classic `{}` notation in a string context is very powerful especially when you have weird variable names:

```
${'y - x'} = 'Ok';
$var = 'y - x';
echo ${$var};
```

will print `Ok` even if the variable name `y - x` isn't valid because of the spaces and the `-` character.

Comment: +1 for you too! I never knew variable names could be that complex. So, could you put an array/object as a variable name?

Comment: @DaveChen, their string representation yes. Although I think there's a length limit for variable names. I don't think it's considered a good practice, therefore I'd avoid it.